# Minizinc - variable value equal 0, 0.5 or 1

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc

I've got array `array[1..num_compute_nodes,1..num_access_nodes,1..num_request] of var 0..1: assignment;`. I need to ensure that value in this array is 0, **0.5** or 1, not 0 or 1.

1.I tried to change that by usign `set of float: domain_cn = { 0, 0.5, 1};` and `array[1..num_compute_nodes,1..num_access_nodes,1..num_request] of domain_cn: assignment;` but this doesn't work (MiniZinc: arithmetic error: arithmetic operation on infinite value).

2. I tried make a constraint `constraint forall(m in 1..num_compute_nodes)(forall(req in 1..num_request )((assignment[m,request_loc[req],req]) = 1 \/(assignment[m,request_loc[req],req]) = 0)\/ ssignment[m,request_loc[req],req]) = 0.5) ));` and `float` instead of `var 0..1` but it doesn't work too (MiniZinc: flattening error)

Is there any other way to solve my problem?

EDIT:
Full Code:
EDIT2: Deleted code

Comment: One way would be to multiply with some constants, e.g. 10 (to get 0, 5, 10), but you might have other float variables in your code? It would help if you show the full model (or a minimal version of it) since then we get the full picture of what your are doing.

Comment: @hakank I pasted full code in main comment. I'm not sure your solution will work for me.

Comment: I copied part of my comment as an answer so you can accept it if you are happy with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This was originally as a comment but moved as an answer.]

One way would be to multiply with some constants, e.g. 10 (to get 0, 5, 10), but you might have other float variables in your code?

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

As @hakank posted, multiplying with constants, by `10` in my example, works! Thanks. I would show it in my code, but I had to delete it.